# Why does build fail with the error - Type or namespace name '' could not be found in the global namespace

Tags: c#, msbuild, namespaces

I am trying to build a project using visual studio as well as MSBuild.exe. When the code is built using visual studio, there are no issues and the build runs successfully, but when built through MSBuild.exe, the following error is thrown - "The type or namespace name 'eCom' could not be found in the global namespace". This error is being recorded from various lines in the code, couple of the erroneous lines have been written below:

```
protected global::eCom.Web.DataViewExtender view3Extender;
```

and

```
using eCom.Web;
```

The dll for 'eCom' is successfully getting created on the server. 
Recently dot net framework 4.6.2 was installed on the build server, I wonder if that has anything to do with the error.

Comment: turn the /verbosity:level up it might give you more clues, however its most likely a framework mismatch or something if it was working before

Comment: For clarity, do you get the error when using MSBuild on your local machine? You've tagged the question with `TFSBuild` is the error only present when you try to build on a build agent?

Comment: Do you run the project with VS Build and MSBuild tasks in TFS, or you just build them locally?

Comment: @JamesReed, when I run the build through MSBuild.exe from the command line, I get exactly the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, the aim is to get the build running from the TFS(which is not happening right now), in order to check whether the build is running through other means or not, we tried MSBuild.exe from command line and we ran the build from visual studio as well.

Comment: Could you add the msbuild command line you are running?